# Checkboxes to show/hide lines in Bokeh (Stock Data Moving Average)

Tags: python, bokeh

The code below shows an example of Bokeh script that uses three check boxes to show/hide lines on a Bokeh chart.

The series are also functions of the original data. Parameters for the functions can be accessed via the sliders. The original data can be adjusted in the text box.

To access, put the following in CMD:

bokeh-server --script C:\Path\to\python\Toggle.py

I heavily used the slider [example](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/server_gallery/sliders_server.html) from the Bokeh website.

The MVA code was from an awesome python website created by [Harrison Kinsley](http://pythonprogramming.net/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from collections import OrderedDict
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.models import Plot, ColumnDataSource
from bokeh.properties import Instance
from bokeh.server.app import bokeh_app
from bokeh.server.utils.plugins import object_page
from bokeh.models.renderers import GlyphRenderer
from bokeh.models.widgets import (
    HBox,
    Slider,
    TextInput,
    VBoxForm,
    CheckboxGroup )

def get_stockdata(ticker):   
        MyStock = pd.read_csv(
        "http://ichart.yahoo.com/table.csv?s="+ticker+"&a=0&b=1&c=2000&d=0&e=1&f=2015",
        parse_dates=['Date'])

    xyvalues = OrderedDict(AdjClose=MyStock['Adj Close'],Date=MyStock['Date'])
    for x in xyvalues.keys():
        xyvalues[x] =xyvalues[x][::-1]

    return xyvalues

def movingaverage(values,window):
        weigths = np.repeat(1.0, window)/window
        smas = np.convolve(values, weigths, 'valid')
        return smas # as a numpy array  



class HackApp(HBox):

extra_generated_classes = [["HackApp", "HackApp", "HBox"]]

inputs = Instance(VBoxForm)

text = Instance(TextInput)

toggle = Instance(CheckboxGroup)
MVA_1 = Instance(Slider)
MVA_2 = Instance(Slider)


plot = Instance(Plot)
source = Instance(ColumnDataSource)
source2 = Instance(ColumnDataSource)
source3 = Instance(ColumnDataSource)

@classmethod
def create(cls):

    obj = cls()

    obj.source = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(x_y=[], y=[]))
    obj.source2 = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(x_z=[], z=[]))
    obj.source3 = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(x_a=[], a=[]))

    obj.text = TextInput(
        title="title", name='title', value='MSFT'
    )

    obj.toggle = CheckboxGroup( labels=["Closes","MVA_1","MVA_2"],active=[0])

    obj.MVA_1 = Slider(
        title="MVA_1", name='MVA_1',
        value=100, start=-0.0, end=500.0, step=10
    )
    obj.MVA_2 = Slider(
        title="MVA_2", name='MVA_2',
        value=200, start=-0.0, end=500.0, step=10
    )


    toolset = "crosshair,pan,reset,resize,save,wheel_zoom"


    plot = figure(title_text_font_size="12pt",
                  plot_height=400,
                  plot_width=400,
                  tools=toolset,
                  title=obj.text.value,
                  x_axis_type = "datetime"
    )




    plot.line('x_y', 'y', source=obj.source,
              line_width=3,
              line_alpha=0.6,
              line_color="red"
    )

    plot.line('x_z', 'z', source=obj.source2,
              line_width=3,
              line_alpha=0.6,
              line_color="blue"
    )

    plot.line('x_a', 'a', source=obj.source3,
              line_width=3,
              line_alpha=0.6,
              line_color="green"
    )

    obj.plot = plot
    obj.update_data()

    obj.inputs = VBoxForm(
        children=[
            obj.text,
            obj.toggle,
            obj.MVA_1,
            obj.MVA_2,

        ]
    )

    obj.children.append(obj.inputs)
    obj.children.append(obj.plot)

    return obj

def checkbox_handler(self,active):

    self.update_data(active)

def setup_events(self):

    super(HackApp, self).setup_events()
    if not self.text:
        return


    self.text.on_change('value', self, 'input_change')


    for w in ["MVA_1", "MVA_2"]:
        getattr(self, w).on_change('value', self, 'input_change')

    self.toggle.on_click(self.checkbox_handler)


def input_change(self, obj, attrname, old, new):

    self.update_data()
    self.plot.title = self.text.value

def update_data(self,hide=False):

    N = 200


    a=1
    b = self.MVA_1.value
    b2 = self.MVA_2.value


    print(self.toggle.active,"self.toggle")

    ticker  = self.text.value
    xyvalues=get_stockdata(ticker)

    y_min = min(xyvalues['AdjClose'] )*0.9
    y_max = max(xyvalues['AdjClose'])*1.1

    MA1 = b
    MA2 = b2

    Av1 = movingaverage(xyvalues['AdjClose'], MA1)
    Av2 = movingaverage(xyvalues['AdjClose'], MA2)
    SP1 = len(xyvalues['Date'][MA1-1:])
    SP2 = len(xyvalues['Date'][MA2-1:])
    Av1=Av1[-SP1:]
    Av2=Av2[-SP2:]
    avgdate1=xyvalues['Date'] [-SP1:]
    avgdate2=xyvalues['Date'] [-SP2:]






    x_y = [] 
    y = []
    x_z = []
    z = []
    x_a = []
    a = []

    for p in self.toggle.active:
        if p ==0:
            x_y = xyvalues['Date'] 
            y = xyvalues['AdjClose'] 
        if p ==1:
            x_z = avgdate1
            z = Av1
        if p ==2:
            x_a = avgdate2
            a = Av2       



    self.source.data = dict(x_y=x_y, y=y)
    self.source2.data = dict(x_z=x_z, z=z)
    self.source3.data = dict(x_a=x_a, a=a)
    self.plot.y_range.start=y_min
    self.plot.y_range.end=y_max


@bokeh_app.route("/bokeh/hack/")
@object_page("sin")
def make_hack():
    app = HackApp.create()
    return app
```

Answer (score 1):

Wasn't happy with the speed of the redraw on every selection, so I've updated this to change the alpha property of the lines instead.  It requires naming and selection of the glyphs which are retrieved in a `_list_attr_splat` object.  Here's the full code again.  Changes are in the create and `checkbox_handler` methods.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from collections import OrderedDict
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.models import Plot, ColumnDataSource
from bokeh.properties import Instance
from bokeh.server.app import bokeh_app
from bokeh.server.utils.plugins import object_page
from bokeh.models.renderers import GlyphRenderer
from bokeh.models.widgets import HBox,Slider,TextInput, VBoxForm, CheckboxGroup 

def get_stockdata(ticker):   
    MyStock = pd.read_csv(
    "http://ichart.yahoo.com/table.csv?s="+ticker+"&a=0&b=1&c=2000&d=0&e=1&f=2015",
    parse_dates=['Date'])

    xyvalues = OrderedDict(AdjClose=MyStock['Adj Close'],Date=MyStock['Date'])
    for x in xyvalues.keys():
        xyvalues[x] =xyvalues[x][::-1]

    return xyvalues

def movingaverage(values,window):
    weigths = np.repeat(1.0, window)/window
    smas = np.convolve(values, weigths, 'valid')
    return smas # as a numpy array  



class HackApp(HBox):

    extra_generated_classes = [["HackApp", "HackApp", "HBox"]]

    inputs = Instance(VBoxForm)

    text = Instance(TextInput)

    toggle = Instance(CheckboxGroup)
    MVA_1 = Instance(Slider)
    MVA_2 = Instance(Slider)


    plot = Instance(Plot)
    source = Instance(ColumnDataSource)
    source2 = Instance(ColumnDataSource)
    source3 = Instance(ColumnDataSource)

    @classmethod
    def create(cls):

        obj = cls()

        obj.source = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(x_y=[], y=[]))
        obj.source2 = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(x_z=[], z=[]))
        obj.source3 = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(x_a=[], a=[]))

        obj.text = TextInput(
            title="title", name='title', value='MSFT'
        )

        obj.toggle = CheckboxGroup( labels=["Closes","MVA_1","MVA_2"],active=[0,1,2])

        obj.MVA_1 = Slider(
            title="MVA_1", name='MVA_1',
            value=100, start=-0.0, end=500.0, step=10
        )
        obj.MVA_2 = Slider(
            title="MVA_2", name='MVA_2',
            value=200, start=-0.0, end=500.0, step=10
        )


        toolset = "crosshair,pan,reset,resize,save,wheel_zoom"


        plot = figure(title_text_font_size="12pt",
                      plot_height=400,
                      plot_width=400,
                      tools=toolset,
                      title=obj.text.value,
                      x_axis_type = "datetime"
        )




        plot.line('x_y', 'y', source=obj.source,
                  line_width=3,
                  line_alpha=0.6,
                  line_color="red",
                  name='closes'
        )

        plot.line('x_z', 'z', source=obj.source2,
                  line_width=3,
                  line_alpha=0.6,
                  line_color="blue",
                  name='av1'
        )

        plot.line('x_a', 'a', source=obj.source3,
                  line_width=3,
                  line_alpha=0.6,
                  line_color="green",
                  name='av2'
        )

        obj.plot = plot
        obj.update_data()

        obj.inputs = VBoxForm(
            children=[
                obj.text,
                obj.toggle,
                obj.MVA_1,
                obj.MVA_2,

            ]
        )

        obj.children.append(obj.inputs)
        obj.children.append(obj.plot)

        return obj

    def checkbox_handler(self,active):

        for n,nm in enumerate(['closes','av1','av2']):
            sel=self.plot.select(dict(name=nm))
            sel[0].glyph.line_alpha= 1 if n in self.toggle.active else 0


    def setup_events(self):

        super(HackApp, self).setup_events()
        if not self.text:
            return


        self.text.on_change('value', self, 'input_change')


        for w in ["MVA_1", "MVA_2"]:
            getattr(self, w).on_change('value', self, 'input_change')

        self.toggle.on_click(self.checkbox_handler)


    def input_change(self, obj, attrname, old, new):

        self.update_data()
        self.plot.title = self.text.value

    def update_data(self,hide=False):

        N = 200


        a=1
        b = self.MVA_1.value
        b2 = self.MVA_2.value


        print(self.toggle.active,"self.toggle")

        ticker  = self.text.value
        xyvalues=get_stockdata(ticker)

        y_min = min(xyvalues['AdjClose'] )*0.9
        y_max = max(xyvalues['AdjClose'])*1.1

        MA1 = b
        MA2 = b2

        Av1 = movingaverage(xyvalues['AdjClose'], MA1)
        Av2 = movingaverage(xyvalues['AdjClose'], MA2)
        SP1 = len(xyvalues['Date'][MA1-1:])
        SP2 = len(xyvalues['Date'][MA2-1:])
        Av1=Av1[-SP1:]
        Av2=Av2[-SP2:]
        avgdate1=xyvalues['Date'] [-SP1:]
        avgdate2=xyvalues['Date'] [-SP2:]






        x_y = [] 
        y = []
        x_z = []
        z = []
        x_a = []
        a = []

        for p in self.toggle.active:
            if p ==0:
                x_y = xyvalues['Date'] 
                y = xyvalues['AdjClose'] 
            if p ==1:
                x_z = avgdate1
                z = Av1
            if p ==2:
                x_a = avgdate2
                a = Av2       



        self.source.data = dict(x_y=x_y, y=y)
        self.source2.data = dict(x_z=x_z, z=z)
        self.source3.data = dict(x_a=x_a, a=a)
        self.plot.y_range.start=y_min
        self.plot.y_range.end=y_max


@bokeh_app.route("/bokeh/hack/")
@object_page("sin")
def make_hack():
    app = HackApp.create()
    return app
```